# Azure Event Hub: Event returns known/unusual Date format

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, message-queue, azure-eventhub

We're using Azure Event Hub (Message Broker) to produce events and store them in that service.

**As events Producer:**
A number of events/messages are pushed to Azure Event Hub space, all those events have the following format (similar):

```
{
body:{
  id: 3123123123,
  name: "name",
  parentId: "12123esczxcxef"
},
properties:{
event:"sample.type-saved",
token:"tokenise data",
**timestamp: 638018037948740000**  //c# tick DateTime
},
//additional info
}
```

`properties.timestamp` value is sent using tick time (Long).

**As events Consumer:**
Using `EventHubConsumerClient.subscribe` the client starts receiving events/messages from our Event Hub in Azure like this:

```
{
    body:{
      id: 3123123123,
      name: "name",
      parentId: "12123esczxcxef"
    },
    properties: {
      event: 'platform.location-sendall',
      token: 'eyJhbGciOiJod...',
      **timestamp: [Object]**
    },
    offset: '4295510040',
    sequenceNumber: 488,
    enqueuedTimeUtc: 2022-10-19T18:38:11.600Z,
    partitionKey: undefined,
    systemProperties: {},
    getRawAmqpMessage: [Function: getRawAmqpMessage]
  }
```

`properties.timestamp` is received and had a `[Object]` date unknown format, **and have no clue how to parse or convert it**.

An example of `properties.timestamp` [Object] is:

```
{
  '0': 8,
  '1': 218,
  '2': 178,
  '3': 1,
  '4': 19,
  '5': 222,
  '6': 23,
  '7': 128
}
```

1. Why is Event Hub returning that kind of timestamp Date value?
2. How to parse this Date value?
3. Any Additional info about this will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Yes, I expect a **timestamp** different value. For E.g. Producer send **timestamp: 638018037948740000**, if you check [Tick time converter](https://www.datetimetoticks-converter.com/) you can see what is expected.

1). By using `properties.timestamp` we consider sending customize date/time value, _e.g SQL DB record **created_at** timestamp._ Therefore, **created_at** (timestamp) is not same as **enqueuedTimeUtc**.
2). Record **created_at** and **enqueuedTimeUtc** needs to be differentiated.

Answer (score 0):

I see, `timestamp` in that context represents `ticks`. In SQL Server you can do this:

```
DECLARE @t bigint = 638018037948740000;

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
  (@t - 599266080000000000) -- subtract ticks for 1900-01-01
   / 10000000 -- divide by microseconds 
   / 86400);  -- then by seconds in a day
```

---

> 2022-10-19 19:16:34.873

In C# you can use `Datetime..Ticks` like in the URL you reference (not a C# person so can't help you there).

Just make sure you don't try to store the output in a `timestamp` column, because in SQL Server that has nothing to do with date/time.